# Texture painting issue in 2.9+

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I've been using blender a while but I don't texture paint often. I'm unsure if there is some new options in 2.9+ or if this is a bug, but my texture painting is all jittery and weird. Also sometimes it just paints big squares instead of the brush. When I open the exact same file in 2.83 it works fine. I've included a video of the issue. Are there any fixes?

Thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grwG99gzmuE

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was the texture size viewport limit setting that wasn't active on my 2.83 version.